# How to render family tree with vis-network

Tags: visnetwork

I'm trying to render a family tree using vis-network, but unsure how to align the arrow for each parents, which also connecting to their child. I've tried a few samples, but the edges looks confusing.

Here's a sample nodes for the grandparents, parents, siblings and child.

```
var nodes = [
  {
    id: "0.1",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Minato Uzumaki',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/7/71/Minato_Namikaze.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20160125175116',
    level: 0
  },
  {
      id: "0.2",
      shape: 'image',
      label: 'Kushina Uzumaki',
      image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/4/4d/Kushina_2.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20150719165408',
      level: 0
  },
  {
    id: "0.3",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Naruto Uzumaki',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/0/09/Naruto_newshot.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20170621101134',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: "1.1",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Hiashi Hyūga',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/e/ee/Hiashi_Hyuga.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20150109142633',
    level: 0
  },
  {
    id: "1.2",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Mother',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/0/0a/Hyuuga_mother.png/revision/latest?cb=20150104203212',
    level: 0
  },
  {
    id: "1.3",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Hinata Hyūga',
    image: 'https://data.whicdn.com/images/191073424/superthumb.jpg?t=1437945312',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: "1.4",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Hanabi Hyūga',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/d/da/Hanabi_Hyuga.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/300?cb=20180314102603',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: "2.1",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Boruto Uzumaki',
    image: 'https://www.anime-planet.com/images/characters/boruto-uzumaki-71171.jpg',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    id: "2.2",
    shape: 'image',
    label: 'Himawari Uzumaki',
    image: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/2/26/Himawari.png/revision/latest?cb=20171115100745',
    level: 2
  },
];

var edges = [
  {from: "0.1", to: "0.2"},
  {from: "0.3", to: "0.1"},
  {from: "0.3", to: "0.2"},

  {from: "1.1", to: "1.2"},
  {from: "1.3", to: "1.1"},
  {from: "1.3", to: "1.2"},
  {from: "1.4", to: "1.1"},
  {from: "1.4", to: "1.2"},
  {from: "1.4", to: "1.3"},

  {from: "0.3", to: "1.3"},

  {from: "2.1", to: "2.2"},
  {from: "0.3", to: "2.1"},
  {from: "0.3", to: "2.2"},
  {from: "1.3", to: "2.1"},
  {from: "1.3", to: "2.2"},
];

var data = {
  nodes: nodes2,
  edges: edges2
};

var container = document.getElementById('network');
var options = {
  nodes: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderWidthSelected: 1,
    shape: "box",
    color: {
      border: 'lightgray',
      background: 'white',
      highlight: {
        border: 'lightgray',
        background: 'lightblue'
      },
      hover: {
        border: 'lightgray',
        background: 'lightblue'
      }
    }
  },
  edges: {
    color: 'lightgray',
    smooth: {
      type: 'cubicBezier',
      forceDirection: 'vertical',
      roundness: 1
    }
  },
  layout: {
    hierarchical: {
      direction: 'UD',
      nodeSpacing: 150
    }
  },
  interaction: {dragNodes :false},
  physics:true,
};

var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

I expect the output will be something like below

[image: sample family tree]

Is it possible to render something like that with vis-network? Or is there a related library able to render like above?

Comment: I don't know about the joined edges. Maybe you could hack it by making a (very) small node, and drawing edges to that from the parents, then down to another small node, and then to the children.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @jsarbour. This is the first time I'm using this library, but I couldn't grasp what you're trying to say. Could you please maybe attach a few samples?

Comment: My idea would be to make a third node located between the parents. Make its size extremely small compared to the parent nodes (check the docs for the size, scaling options for nodes), and use it to mock the structure that you have described.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you to add some extra nodes in between the main nodes.
those will be defined as relation nodes.
the red nodes will define as a couple, and the blue nodes will be defined as a descendant.

both blue and red could be hidden.
[image]

Good luck!